# Licensing Windows Server AWS

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services

I have a instance with Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard in AWS. the instances is a m4.large and run a application for locations users.
The instances is in on-demand model.
i know that AWS gives me the license, but when i access the instances, i see a message requesting  a license.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW8ie.png)

In the instance I have applications but I don't want to relaunch instances.
Anyone know the solution?

Comment: Did you import this instance from a local VMware image? or create it from an AWS AMI?